# Как создать блог с добовлением статей

Tags: html, python, django

Пытаюся создать простой блог не не как не могу добовлять статьи по сути готовая версия уже есть но нужно сделать это все одним классом во vies.py что то типо этого

```
def all_articles(request):
    articles = Article.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('all_articles.html', {'articles': articles}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def one_article_by_slug(request, slug):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'one_article.html', {'article': article}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

models.py

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    post = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='', default="default_value")
    whoAreYou = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Четко!')
    textComment = models.TextField(blank=False, default='Четко!')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

post.html это сама статья

```
{% block content %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
            <h1 class=" text-info">{{articles.title}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
          <p> {{articles.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
            <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
      </div>

        <h4>Comments</h4>


<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  {% if comments %}
    {% for CommentModel in comments %}
      {{ CommentModel.WhoAreYou }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

  {{ form }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

posts.html здесь список статей

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in articles_list  %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="/news/{{article.id}}"> <h1> {{article.title}} </h1> </a>
          <h3 align="right">{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    path('news/', ListView.as_view(queryset=Articles.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:20],template_name="news/posts.html")),
    path('<int:pk>/', DetailView.as_view(model=Articles, template_name="news/post.html")),
    path('aboutUs', views.aboutUs, name='aboutUs'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Не совсем понятный вопрос: "но не как не могу перенести ее из urls.py в класс во views.py".. что конкретно у вас не получается перенести?
Во urls.py - у вас хранятся роуты, причем тогда views.py, что это и зачем?

Comment: Короче нужно заменить вместо всегол этого urls.py одним классов во views.py чтобы он вызывался во urls.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**news/urls.py**

```
path('', ArticlesList.as_view(), name='articles_list'),
path('<int:pk>/', ArticleDetail.as_view(), name='article_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
class ArticlesList(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'news/posts.html'

class ArticleDetail(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'news/post.html'
```

**posts.html**

```
{% extends "ShapeHtml/wrapper.html" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for article in object_list  %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <p><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ article.img.url }}"/></p>
      </div>

      <div class="panel-body">
          <a href="{% url 'article_detail' article.pk %}"> <h1> {{article.title}} </h1> </a>
          <h3 align="right">{{article.date|date:"d-m-Y"}}</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**post.html**

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h1 class=" text-info">{{object.title}}</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <p> {{object.post|safe|linebreaks}}  </p>
    <h3 align="right" class=" text-info"> Опубликованно: {{articles.date|date:"d-m-Y в H:i"}}</h3>
</div>
```